# Retreving all user defined class from classpath/classloader

Tags: java, annotations, classpath, classloader

I am planning to write annotation based approach.

i want to find all user defined class when the main program runs. I want to avoid all SDK based classes and list all classes only in the classpath.

This is because, i can run my annotation reading on all my class that available in the classpath. or if any other approach please let me know.

How to do this ?

Comment: why you want to retrieve them  ?

Comment: Could you do you annotation reading at compile time? That'd probably be a better approach.

Comment: The idea is to read all the class in all the user defined package and read the annotations.

Comment: @TomHawtin  Is it possible to do in Compile time ? again i need to get all the class list!

Comment: Whilst compiling the classes with the annotations, yes. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#processing

Comment: @TomHawtin I am now more curious :) Any idea... How exactly jSdk/ JEE works with annotations ? JEE6 @WebServlet etc how its read and processed ! ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring's [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html).